need someone to help me with this discord.js code
i have this code that logs messages to my  other server and it works fine BUTTTT it sends them in message form example: '@dyno said: hello' thats the format but id prefer it to send them in embeds with the title as the user who sent the message and the description to have the message content heres  my existing code
client.on('messageCreate', message => {


  if (message.author.bot) {
    return;
  }


  console.log("Message received:", message.content); // Checkpoint
  if (message.guild && message.guild.id === 'my_server_id') {
    console.log("Message received from the correct guild."); // Checkpoint
    const destinationChannel = client.channels.cache.get('my_destination_channel_id');
    if (destinationChannel) {
      console.log("Destination channel found."); // Checkpoint
      destinationChannel.send(`**${message.author.tag}** said: ${message.content}`);
    } else {
      console.log(`Destination channel not found in the destination guild.`);
    }
  }
});



Please edit your question and provide the details demonstrating what you have attempted to resolve your question, and explain at what point in your attempt(s) you didn't get the result you expect.  As it currently reads, your question is asking us to modify your code to meet your requirements.  That's not how this site works.

if ur not gonna help whats the point in commenting telling me what to do

Ok, what I can understand you want the messaged the bot send to you received as embedded message.
Also fellow stackoverflow people I am not a professional and still learning
If I understand this correctly and can't test it at the moment but reading the discord.js docs it should come out to this.
https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#embed-preview
// at the top of your file
const { EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js');

// inside a command, event listener, etc.
const exampleEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
    .setColor(0x0099FF)
    .setTitle({message.author.tag})
    .addFields(
        { name: 'Message', value: {message.content} },
    )

Channel.send({ embeds: [exampleEmbed] });
What your code will become I hope if it works is this,


    // at the top of your file
const { EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js')
client.on('messageCreate', message => {


  if (message.author.bot) {
    return;
  }


  console.log("Message received:", message.content); // Checkpoint
  if (message.guild && message.guild.id === 'my_server_id') {
    console.log("Message received from the correct guild."); // Checkpoint
    const destinationChannel = client.channels.cache.get('my_destination_channel_id');
    if (destinationChannel) {
      console.log("Destination channel found."); // Checkpoint
const exampleEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
.setColor(0x0099FF)
.setTitle(message.author.tag)
.addFields(
    { name: 'Message', value: message.content },
)

destinationChannel.send({ embeds: [exampleEmbed] });
    } else {
      console.log(`Destination channel not found in the destination guild.`);
    }
  }
});




Yep works a treat thanks so much :)
